# Update TwiML while keeping Media Stream

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

**Summary**

I want to use `<Say>` and `<Gather>` verbs at any given time while keeping Media Stream connection.

**Description**

I wrote `<Connect>` verb to sent media back to the call based on [this url](https://jp.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream#bi-directional-media-streams).
However, updating TwiML to use  verbs will of course override  and cut it off.

Any good ideas for updating TwiML while keeping Media Steam?

Comment: Can you please explain your use case. Why are you trying to change the TwiML while being in a call?

Comment: @IObert I appreciate your comment. I want to transcribe in real-time with my program and use `<Say>` to speech answer created by my program. Additionally, I want caller to answer with key for choice questions.

Comment: I think I understand your use-case now. I'm still not if TwiML is the right choice for you here. TwiML is static and you don't update it while users are in a call.


I would assume you're better off using Twilio Studio to define the flow and trigger the recording there.